# Is there a way to fix a singular controller in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I accidentally generated a singular controller comm_log without 's'. 's' was added to controller name, helpers, views, specs and routes. The customer_comm_log_path(f.customer_id, f.id) seems not right.

The relation is a comm log belongs to a customer and a customer has many comm logs.

```
  resources :customers do
    resources :comm_logs
  end
```

The output of rake routes (related) is:

```
         comm_logs_index GET    /comm_logs/index(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"comm_logs", :action=>"index"}
           comm_logs_new GET    /comm_logs/new(.:format)                                        {:controller=>"comm_logs", :action=>"new"}
        comm_logs_create GET    /comm_logs/create(.:format)                                     {:controller=>"comm_logs", :action=>"create"}
          comm_logs_show GET    /comm_logs/show(.:format)                                       {:controller=>"comm_logs", :action=>"show"}
       comm_logs_destroy GET    /comm_logs/destroy(.:format)                                    {:controller=>"comm_logs", :action=>"destroy"}

      customer_comm_logs GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
                         POST   /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
   new_customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
  edit_customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
       customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
                         PUT    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
                         DELETE /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
```

Is there a way to fix the singular controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `script/destroy your_controller_name` using the same controller name used to create it.

Comment: Besides destroying the one generated, is there a way to fix it? Or it is not a good idea to fix.

Comment: destroy/redo is probably the easy way to handle this.

Comment: I agree with user938363, it's best to destroy and do again.  As always, save a copy before destroying.  Doing this (destrot) is also a good idea as it removed test stubs and the like, which, otherwise, are often left 'lying around'